# Not able to use Open CV in Sublime Text

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to use OpenCv in Sublime text. Whenever I try to build the script, it throws this error -

```
File "C:\Users\ATHARVA\Desktop\Python\circle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 158, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import _numpy_tester

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import decorators as dec

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\decorators.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .nose_tools.decorators import *

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\nose_tools\decorators.py", line 20, in <module>

    from .utils import SkipTest, assert_warns

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\nose_tools\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp

  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random

ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I am not able to understand why this error is coming. Can someone help by pointing out what the problem is?

***Edit:- The issue has been resolved.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have created a file with name Random.py / random.py find and delete it should solve the problem.

> Not able to import Ope CV in Sublime Text

You didnt import cv2 (OpenCV) either. Make Sure You have installed OpenCV. 
Install opencv if you havent installed it yet. From windows command line type:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and import is as

```
import cv2
```